# Why does my footer background lose RGBA transparency when set to position:static?

Tags: css, position, transparency, footer, rgba

I am attempting to style a footer element so that the background is transparent using RGBA colours. When the element is set to `position: absolute` the transparency works fine, but when set to `position: static` the transparency is lost.

I have tried targeting the `.footerDiv` as well as `footer.footerDiv` and also tried setting a white transparent background, but couldn't get anything to work.

I am using Zurb Foundation 6 as my framework. I have researched and tried some different fiddles but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I need the footer to remain static in order to remain responsive for different screen sizes. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<footer class="footerDiv">
    <div class="row" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
         <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center col1" data-equalizer-watch>
            <img class="jamboHealth" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/health.svg" alt="Jambo Health Logo">
            <img class="jamboConstruct" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/construction.svg" alt="Jambo Construction Logo">
            <img class="jamboDigi" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/digital.svg" alt="Jambo Digital Logo">
            <p class="text-center">0845 424 9753</p>
            <div class="divideAlign">
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--col1-->

        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center col2" data-equalizer-watch>
           <img class="jamboEdu" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/education.svg" alt="Jambo Education Logo">
           <img class="jamboManu" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/manufacturing.svg" alt="Jambo Manufacturing Logo">
           <p class="text-center">01872 22 33 66</p>
           <div class="divider">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--col2-->

        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center col3" data-equalizer-watch>
           <img class="jamboInt" src="../assets/img/assetLogos/international.svg" alt="Jambo International Logo">
           <p class="text-center">+44161 393 708</p>
           <div class="divider">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--col3-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
position: static;
bottom: 0;
padding-top: 1rem;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: a quick word of advice - if you provide a link to a fiddle in your question, you are much more likely to entice responders

Answer (score 0):

The position doesn't influence RGBA transparancy, looking at this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/y8hwqq2m/3/

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.footerDiv {
  position: absolute;
}
.footerDiv2 {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footerDiv">
  <div class="row" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center col1" data-equalizer-watch>
      Some content positioned: absolute;
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<footer class="footerDiv2">
  <div class="row" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center col1" data-equalizer-watch>
      Some content positioned: static;
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Are you sure the background of the element underneath isn't white when setting the position to static?